# The item configure method didn't work in Tkinter

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, graphics, tkinter

I tried to use the Tkinter library for my small project in python.  I create a 500 by 500 square with 10000 small square in it.

And I want each small square turns black when user click on it.  Can someone please tell me why, I would really appreciate it.  Here is the graphics code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from button import *

class AppFrame(Frame):




def __init__(self):

    self.root = Tk()
    self.root.geometry = ("1000x1000")
    self.f = Frame(self.root, relief = 'sunken', width = 600, height = 600)
    self.w = Canvas(self.f,width = 505, height =505)

    ##get the x, y value whenever the user make a mouse click
    self.w.bind("<Button-1>", self.xy)
    self.bolist = []

    for k in range(1,101):
        for i in range(1, 101):

            button = Buttons(self.w, i * 5, k * 5, i * 5 + 5, k * 5 + 5)
            self.bolist.append(button)

    self.f.grid(column =0, columnspan = 4)
    self.w.grid(column = 0)

    self.root.mainloop()


def xy (self, event):
    self.x, self.y = event.x, event.y
    print (self.x, self.y)
    ##check each button if it's clicked
    for hb in self.bolist:
        if hb.clicked(self.x, self.y):
            print ("hurry")
            hb.activate()
```

And

```
##button.py
from Tkinter import *


class Buttons:

def __init__(self,canvas,bx,by,tx,ty):

    self.canvas = canvas
    self.rec = canvas.create_rectangle((bx,by,tx,ty),fill = "lightgray",
                                       activefill= 'black', outline = 'lightgray')


    self.xmin = bx
    self.xmax = tx
    self.ymin = by
    self.ymax = ty
    ##print (bx, by, tx, ty)
def clicked(self, px, py):
    return (self.active and self.xmin <= px <= self.xmax and
            self.ymin <= py <= self.ymax)
def activate(self):
    self.canvas.itemconfigure(slef.rec, fill = 'black')
    self.active = True
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The indentation of your code is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't initialize the `active` attribute, so it doesn't exist until the cell becomes active. To fix that, add `self.active = False` inside the `__init__` method of `Buttons`.

You also have a typo in this line (notice you use `slef` rather than `self`):

```
self.canvas.itemconfigure(slef.rec, fill = 'black')
```

Instead of a global binding on the canvas, it would be more efficient to set a binding on each individual rectangle. You can then use the binding to pass the instance of the `Buttons` class to the callback. This way you don't have to iterate over several thousand widgets looking for the one that was clicked on.

To do this, use the `tag_bind` method of the canvas. You can make it so that your main program passes in a reference to a function to call when the rectangle is clicked, then the binding can call that method and pass it a reference to itself.

For example:

```
class Buttons:

    def __init__(self,canvas,bx,by,tx,ty, callback):
        ...
        self.rec = canvas.create_rectangle(...)
        self.canvas.tag_bind(self.rec, "<1>", 
            lambda event: callback(self))
        ...


class AppFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(...):
        ...
            button = Buttons(..., self.callback)
        ...

    def callback(self, b):
        b.activate()
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I totally forgot I can bind the event in the Button class!  It works now!

Answer (score 1):

Here, I looked at your code, debugged it, and made some adjustments. It works now.
Just keep both the scripts in one folder and run your AppFrame script (the second one in this answer)

```
##button.py
from Tkinter import *

class Buttons:

    def __init__(self,canvas,bx,by,tx,ty):

        self.canvas = canvas
        self.rec = canvas.create_rectangle((bx,by,tx,ty),fill = "lightgray", activefill= 'black', outline = 'lightgray')


        self.xmin = bx
        self.xmax = tx
        self.ymin = by
        self.ymax = ty
        ##print (bx, by, tx, ty)
    def clicked(self, px, py):
        return (self.xmin <= px <= self.xmax and
                self.ymin <= py <= self.ymax)
    def activate(self):
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.rec, fill = 'black')
```

AND

```
from Tkinter import *
from button import *

class AppFrame(Frame):

    def __init__(self):

        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry = ("1000x1000")
        self.f = Frame(self.root, relief = 'sunken', width = 600, height = 600)
        self.w = Canvas(self.f,width = 505, height =505)

        ##get the x, y value whenever the user make a mouse click
        self.w.bind("<Button-1>", self.xy)
        self.bolist = []

        for k in range(1,101):
            for i in range(1, 101):

                button = Buttons(self.w, i * 5, k * 5, i * 5 + 5, k * 5 + 5)
                self.bolist.append(button)

        self.f.grid(column =0, columnspan = 4)
        self.w.grid(column = 0)

        self.root.mainloop()


    def xy (self, event):
        self.x, self.y = event.x, event.y
        print (self.x, self.y)
        ##check each button if it's clicked
        for hb in self.bolist:
            if hb.clicked(self.x, self.y):
                print ("hurry")
                hb.activate()

newApp = AppFrame()
```

Comment: your answer would be much more useful if you described what you did to make it work. It's very difficult to try to compare your solution to the original line-by-line, looking for what you did differently. Remember, your goal as an answer-writer is to teach, not just to provide code for someone to blindly cut and paste.

Comment: Sorry. You're right. I'm kinda new to this.

What I did was I added `newApp = AppFrame()` to the second file above. This is because you actually have to make an instance of a class to use it.

Secondly, I removed `self.active and` part and the `self.active = True` part since it is not an attribute of the button.

That was enough to make it work. @Bryan Oakley, I hope that explained it properly enough.

Comment: Thank you for your patient!  I forgot to write the self.active part.  That is helpful!